# mysql get result from join table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, group-by

I have a tables person and exam.

```
person

-------------
id  | name
-------------
1   | J.Doe
2   | Snow

exam
----------------------------------------------------
id | person_id | exam_no | exam_status | pass_date 
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1       | PASS        | 2020-01-01
2  | 1         | 2       | PASS        | 2020-01-10
3  | 1         | 3       | PASS        | 2020-01-20
4  | 2         | 1       | PASS        | 2020-01-01
5  | 2         | 2       | NOT PASS    | NULL
6  | 2         | 3       | NOT PASS    | NULL
```

I want to show data where all exam is PASS, show the latest exam pass_date. like table below

```
----------------------
person_id | pass_date
----------------------
1         | 2020-01-20
2         | NULL
```

what query to get it?
please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and conditional expressions:

```
select 
    person_id,
    case when max(exam_status = 'NOT PASS') = 0 then max(pass_date) end pass_date
from exam
group by person_id
```

Note that for this sample data, you don't need to bring in the `person` table to get the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You question is ambiguous.  If you want all exams *for a particular person* to pass, then I would suggest:

```
select p.*,
       (select max(e.pass_date)
        from exam e
        where e.person_id = p.id
        having sum(e.exam_status = 'PASS') = count(*)
       ) as pass_date
from person p;
```

However, you might also mean that you want *all* possible examples to be passed.  If so:

```
select p.*,
       (select max(e.pass_date)
        from exam e
        where e.person_id = p.id
        having sum(e.exam_status = 'PASS') = ee.num_exams
       ) as pass_date     
from person p cross join
     (select count(distinct exam_no) as num_exams from exam) ee;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but those data above is just an example. I have another case that similar with the question.